# Soundpool not looping in android 4.3

Tags: android, soundpool

I have a couple of apps in which I use soundpool to loop the sound of a ticking clock, this works fine in all previous versions of android but after upgrading to android 4.3 the sound no longer loops but just plays once.  I know I can use MediaPlayer to loop it instead but this doesn't sound as good.  Is there an easy work around for this, will android fix the bug, or do I have to make do with MediaPlayer.

Answer (score 5):

Check this link.
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58113
Soundpool stopped working in 4.3

Comment: Thanks, no obvious solutions, but it's good to know other people are having the same problems, I guess if enough people report the problem google might fix the bug.

Comment: yeap, they should fix the broken api

Answer (score 3):

When calling 
SoundPool.play(int soundID, float leftVolume, float rightVolume, int priority, int loop, float rate)
I set the rate to 0.99f instead of 1, actually anything but 1 appears to work. It loops as expected on android 5.0.1. If rate set to 1 it loops about twice then it stops.
I had the same loop problem, however it works on android 4.3 but not 5.0.1 when using rate 1.

Comment: Funny enough, this works fine for now. :P
(Testing with Nexus 5 on 5.1.1)