# Android soundpool loop not working: Alternative

Tags: android, audio, multimedia

I want to play a short sound (.ogg) on Android and tried soundpool.
The sound should be played several times so I used sound pool loop parameter. On my Nexus 4 (JB4.3), the loop parameter in soundpool gets ignored and the sound will only be played once.

It seems to be a bug in soundpool:
[Soundpool not looping in android 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17971458/soundpool-not-looping-in-android-4-3)

What is the best alternative for soundpool to play a short sound and repeating that sound?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was being discussed in the android issue tracker  (http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58113) .

There is apparently no straight forward workaround.

In audioTrack, sound looping can be achieved with setLoopPoints() API call.

```
audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
            sampleRateInHz, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, totalNumOfSamples,
            AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);
    audioTrack.write(pcmdata, 0, pcmdata.length);
    //the end frame is the length/4 if it is 16bites
    audioTrack.setLoopPoints(0,pcmdata.length/4,-1);
    audioTrack.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have find the Solution to fix the problem of looping.

I don't know how but is works with this limitation.

soundpool that can Loop the sound only file that `size` is `< 1mb.`