# Background looping Mediaplayer

Tags: android, media-player

I am working on an application which loops sounds in background but when file completes and starts again it have some delay user can notice there is some gap in looping

I have tried the .ogg format files but still have issue

i am using this code to play and loop sounds

```
player = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getIdentifier("raw/" + file, "raw", getPackageName()));
player.start();                                 
player.setLooping(true);
```

I sused .ogg format files as answered here

File link is here

[Link to ogg file](http://rpg.hamsterrepublic.com/wiki-images/b/bc/Rain2.ogg)

[Soundpool not looping in android 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17971458/soundpool-not-looping-in-android-4-3)

Comment: and the audio file itself has no gap at the beginning or at the end of the track that would help cause this?

Comment: link to ogg file please check the edit

Comment: This is a nerve wrecking, known-to-Google, bug.